# How to use fine tuned models in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I used trained AlexNet to fine tune on my database. Now, when I have stored the session I got three file **model.ckpt.meta, model.ckpt.index, model.ckpt.data.** 
Now, how can use the new weights and model to predict on other images.

Also, is there is any way to store weights in .npy format?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables), you save variables with a Saver object, and load with the same. Such as in the following:

```
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.Variable(..., name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(..., name="v2")

saver = tf.train.Saver()

if training:
  initialize()
  train()
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt") # save your variables

if testing:
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt") # load your variables
  predict()
```

TensorFlow variables are saved in their own format. To save variables as Numpy you need to get the tensors from session as numpy arrays and then save/load with Numpy as mentioned in [Numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html):

```
# After training
v1_np = sess.run(v1, your_data) # get numpy array from TensorFlow
np.save('/tmp/123', v1_np) # save to numpy format

# something else happens here

# Load the numpy variables
v1_np = vnp.load('/tmp/123.npy')
v1 = tf.Variable(v1_np) # initialize your tf variable with numpy values
```

Why you'd want to do this is mysterious